# Pixel Launcher isn’t responding on emulator Android

Tags: android

I tried to compile the application but in the emulator I get the message  "pixel launcher isn t responding". I changed the performance in Software, but still it appears.plzzzz help, i ve tried 3 days to resolve this but with no results

Answer (score 1):

clearing launcher app data may help,

```
adb shell pm clear com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher
```

I hope it would helpful for you

Comment: I tried to use the adb command but I found some problems. I do not find the sdk folder to be able to use the command

Comment: You should must try Genymotion because quite be possible On Genymotion this error will be gone

Comment: I installed GenyMotion, but in android studio I Api 28, and in GenyMotion I can not start a device with Api 28

Comment: Have you installed Genymotion Emulator with Api 28 ? & Have you tried this ? Google Pixel 9.0-API 28 & Google Pixel 2 9.0-API 28

Comment: And Have you installed Genymotion Plugin in your android studio ? To install the Genymotion plugin for Android Studio
In Android Studio, go to File/Settings (for Windows and Linux) or to Android Studio/Preferences (for Mac OS X)
Select Plugins and click Browse Repositories.
Right-click on Genymotion and click Download and install. To see Genymotion plugin icon, display the toolbar by clicking View > Toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I opened the AVD manager, I `wiped the data` of the emulator, then I did a `cold boot` and the error went away. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

1- Try `wipe data`, i have faced this problem before and this was the solution.
2- Check if there is any update from `SDK Manager`.
3- Deleting this emulated device and recreate a new one may help you.

Comment: I tried wipe data and now it shows me “system ui isn t responding”. I checked if there are updates and I deleted and made another emulator and the same problem I have. I'm desperate